# Can't share on Whatsapp from my website

Tags: wordpress, url, web, sharing, whatsapp

I have developed a website which is mainly used in mobile phones. I want to allow users to share link directly from a page.
I have tried something like : `whatsapp://send?text='. get_permalink() .'` 
but it just send the text, i want something like preview, otherwise send an image with a followed caption with the related link,

How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you adding `data-action="share/whatsapp/share"` ?

Please check on my [blog post](http://niralar.com/whatsapp-share-button-website/). It will send me the link with preview image.
Did you tried static link, Without `get_permalink()` ?

[image]